# Laravel 5.2 asset implementation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I try to open the assets,I added on my page on the source (css, js),I get the log error at the end of the page.

Here's what I've tried so far:

**homepage.blade.php**

```
<link href="{{{asset('/css/bootstrap.css') }}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Composer.json**

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2"
    }
```

**composer update** from console.

added to **app.php->providers**

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class
```

added to **app.php->aliases**

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class
```

**I get this in laravel.log:**

```
local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found' in /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:146
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this will do the trick, but I usually use only two `{{`. So it will be `{{ asset() }}`. However I don't think that is your problem, double check if the files really exists in your vendor folder.

Comment: Try Collective\HTML\HtmlServiceProvider::class

Comment: @DevinGray which doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Thomas Van der Veen no, it doesn't change my laravel log or solve my problem.

Comment: remove the provider, composer update then add the provider again (ends with a ,)

Comment: try "illuminate/html": "~5.0" in composer, Then do a composer update Wait for the update to finish, then in config/app.php add this:

'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider', 
to the providers array and this:

'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',

Comment: @DevinGray now i get this: 'Command "optimize" is not defined.' so every time something's missing.

Comment: Got answer from here, http://thegeekyland.blogspot.co.za/2015/11/class-illuminatehtmlhtmlserviceprovider.html.. Try run php artisan serve and see if it works? if not it may be a missing service provider

Comment: @DevinGray thanks but now i'm getting this: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()

Comment: That one I do know the answer to :) go to project/vendor/illuminate/html/HtmlServiceProvider.php and all instances of bindShared has been renamed to $app->singleton()

Comment: it is an update from 5.1 to 5.2 error, see here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/call-to-undefined-method-illuminatefoundationapplicationbindshared

Comment: there's a `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider` inside `config/app.php->providers`? Remove if exists, and run `composer dump -o`

Comment: Have you dumped autoload via composer ?

Comment: @ShadyAtef yes, nothing changed.

Comment: I have the configuration you listed in your original question in a project and it works for me. Did you check that vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/HtmlServiceProvider.php exists? Sometimes it helps to manually clean the cache directory/Autoloader with a bad conscience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

The problem was about setting the virtual host settings wrong. So i wasn't able to reach the true path.

I re-set the vhost configuration and it works now.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAdmin mysite@mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/public

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory "/var/www/html/mysite">
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Reference: http://vaguelyuseful.info/2016/02/02/installing-laravel-5-2-on-ubuntu-15-10-and-apache2/

Thank you all again.

Answer (score 1):

change this :

```
<link href="{{{asset('/css/bootstrap.css') }}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

into this :

```
<link href="{{URL::asset('/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```